# recursively add directory name to file name

Tags: files, rename

Given the following structure:

```
source/
  dir1/
   file1.ext1
   file2.ext2
  dir2/
   file3.ext3
    dir3/
     file4.ext4
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
destination/
 dir1file1.ext1
 dir1file2.ext2
 dir2file3.ext3
 dir3file4.ext4
```

In other words, I want to move all the files, recursively, from source to destination, appending the original subdirectory name to the file name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Perl rename and `find`:

```
$ find source -type f | rename -n 's:(^|.*/)([^/]*)/([^/]*)$:destination/$2$3:'
rename(source/dir2/file3.ext3, destination/dir2file3.ext3)
rename(source/dir2/dir3/file4.ext4, destination/dir3file4.ext4)
rename(source/dir1/file1.ext1, destination/dir1file1.ext1)
rename(source/dir1/file2.ext2, destination/dir1file2.ext2)
```

The regex `(^|.*/)([^/]*)/([^/]*)` saves the last two components of the path (the filename and parent directory) as the second and third matched groups.

The `destination` directory must exist before running this. The `-n` is for testing, remove it for actually moving the files.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code does exactly what I asked for, and with a minor modification, exactly what I need. I forgot I'd want a separator between dir and file ($2-$3). Even I can do that.