# Move files to parent directory, prefixing file name with former subdirectory name

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename, mv

I have a folder `parentdir` with many directories like this:

```
$ tree parentdir/subdir_1

parentdir/subdir_1
├── important.txt
├── important_001.txt
├── important_002.log
├── important_007.bmp
├── something
├── else.mp3
├── nothing.000
└── ignore.me
```

What I want is to move all files with a name starting with `important` to the parent directory `parentdir` and renaming them by prefixing each file name with the name of the subdirectory they came from.

For example, `parentdir/subdir_1/important_001.txt` should be moved/renamed to `parentdir/subdir_1-important_001.txt`.

How can I most easily perform this bulk move/rename operation on a huge directory?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/870885/158442?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `parentdir` you could use

```
for f in ./*/important*; do rename -n 's#\./([^/]+)/(.*)#$1-$2#' "$f" ; done
```

Remove `-n` after testing to actually move and rename

#### Explanation

- `s#old#new#` replace `old` with `new`
- `\./([^/]+)/(.*)` match literal `./` then save some characters other than `/`, then match `/`, then save the rest
- `$1-$2` the two saved patterns separated by `-`

Ditching the path separator moves the files to `parentdir` by force

**Afterthought**: more simply in this case you could just use `s#/#-#` to replace `/` with `-`, omitting `./` from the start

```
for f in */important*; do rename -n 's#/#-#' "$f" ; done
```

Comment: A wildcard pattern in a really huge directory will overflow the command line buffer -- better to feed the names into a loop one at a time, but since the answer was accepted, I guess no overflow occurred.